# More confusion about by/until - starting a question

Tags: time

How should I write the following sentence like a native does:

> **By what time** did you stay up for work last night? 
>   **Until what time** did you stay up for work last night?

I think both of them are incorrect.

Please note that this question has nothing to do with my previous threads. I am asking about the structure of until/by + "what time" at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: If in this context, staying up is only due to the *work*, why create ambiguity? Simply ask - When did you sleep last night! :)... However, I'd prefer - *What time you were uptil the last night, finishing work?*

Comment: Thanks @MaulikV, but I'm sure that's not my desirable answer, which I'm waiting for.

Comment: There are several variations on this depending on what exactly you mean:  *How late were you at work last night?* (doesn't imply when they went to bed, just when they left to go home)  *How late were you up working last night?* (does imply that they went to bed immediately after quitting for the night) *What time did you get to sleep last night* (context can imply they were working until they went to sleep).  *Did you pull an all-nighter?* (Assumes they will contradict you and tell you what time they left or went to sleep)

Comment: Thank you @Jim, for the informative comment of you, but one more question; How about if I change the sentences in the following way: (then I need to change again or not):
- By what time did you work last night? 
- Until what time did you work last night?

Comment: *Until what time did you work last night* is grammatically correct, but not something a native is likely to say in informal conversation between friends or coworkers.

Comment: Perfect; and what the natives say in such a moment in casual / spoken language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion because of your example sentences, which seem to be drawing attention away from the issue you want to discuss.

*Stay up* is a phrasal verb that means *stay awake* or *remain out of bed*. If I say, "I stayed up until midnight last night," that essentially means "I went to bed at midnight last night," or, "I fell asleep at midnight last night."

So, the phrase *stay up for work* seems a little awkward. It's not something I would normally say, but I suppose I could contrive of a situation where I might say it. For example, let's say I know someone who is on call. They tell her, "You need to be ready to come into work if we call you. However, if we haven't called you by a certain time, you won't be called at all." If I don't know what that time is, and I'm curious, I could ask:

> Until what time did you stay up for work last night?

meaning, what time were you able to finally go to bed?

Perhaps you meant "stay at work", which makes a lot more sense:

> How late did you stay at work last night?

meaning, "What time did you finish work last night, and head home?"

If I wanted to express with one of those two dastardly prepositions (*by* or *until*), I would use *until*:

> Until what time were you here at work last night?

Another possibility is that the person starts work at an odd time (say, 3AM). If I knew this person didn't go to sleep before starting work, I might ask:

> How late did you stay up before going to work last night?

Your sentence asks about **until/by + what time**, but many of these questions are asked with "how long" (or "how late") instead, which is why it's hard to give you a straight answer to your question.

---

Here's a situation where I might use this phrasing. You and I plan to go camping this weekend. I need to get some details before we can finalize our plans. Later tonight, I'll start doing some research. That is the backdrop for this conversation:

> After you figure things out, just give me a call, and let me know the plans, okay?
>   *I can do that, but it might be kind of late before I get it figured out. **Until what time can I call?***
>   I should be up until 11; you can call me any time before then.
>   *Sounds good*.
>   If I haven't heard from you **by that time**, I'll look for a voice mail in the morning.

*Until what time can I call?* is asking how late it will be before it would be considered impolite to rouse you from bed with a phone call.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is wrong. As for the second one, it isn't grammatically wrong, but as Jim has already told you it's isn't something a native speaker would say. You could say: "What time did you finish work last night?" As for "by/until" , they are both prepositions. Until= before the time when something happens and not after it.eg. "He worked for the company until he retired" It is rarely used in questions. "By"= no later than a specified time.eg. "You must finish the report by Friday afternoon."You won't see "by" used in the beginning of a question like the one you have written. You can say:"Had you finished work by 11:30 yesterday?'""
"Until what time did you stay up for work last night" can be written"= "Did you stay up until very late last night?"